# ListFragment setListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listfragment, listadapter

I have an Activity which layout holds a DrawerLayout (from supported library) with a FrameLayout + ListView.
In my FrameLayout I have a ListFragment, which looks like this (aprox):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post,
            container, false);

    mListHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,
            container, false);
    mListFooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer,
            container, false);

    // inflate xml layout into Views
    linkUI();

    // set Views actions
    setAction();

    return fragmentView;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // add header and footer before settings adapter (to work in
    // pre-KITKAT versions)
    getListView().addHeaderView(mListHeader);
    getListView().addFooterView(mListFooter);

    if (listAdapter == null) {
        listAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
    }

    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    pbListLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    setListAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Problem is, there seems to be a problem at: setListAdapter(listAdapter) line from onActivityCreated, that throws this exception:

```
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:519)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:505)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:448)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:182)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at com.example.PostFragment.onActivityCreated(PostFragment.java:138)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5006)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
```

01-24 18:20:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(20789):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What could be wrong with this code?

Comment: that means class that you are using is not compatible with what you have written in import.

Comment: Inflate the header and footer views without passing the container parameter, `mListHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);` for example. Also, please don't prefix your question's title with `Android`, the tag at the bottoms is more than enough.

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks a lot! copy-pasted the line above them and didn't look for any differences.. I'll try to be more carefull. Editted question title too. If you like, post it as an answer to my question, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code of the header and footer use:

```
mListHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
mListFooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
```

If you use your current code the inflated views `mListHeader` and `mListFooter` will have as `LayoutParams` an instance of `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`(you pass the `container` as the second parameter which basically suggest the type of the parent that the inflated views will have). However when you call `setListAdapter()` the `ListView` does some work under the hood where it will iterate over the views above and access their `LayoutParams`(which the `ListView` expects to be an instance of `AbsListView.LayoutParams`) resulting in the `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the listview as parameter instead of the fragment's container:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mListHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, view, false);
    mListFooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, view, false);
}
```

And remove your entire `onCreateView` method as `ListFragment` already calls `inflater.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.list_content, container, false);`

If you still have the same error, then I think you might have a problem in your MyAdapter.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I see your answer works great, but the downfall to this is forcing me to use min api level 13, and I'd like to use min 9 (forgot to mention it in my Question). I'll use Luksprog advice to solve this. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: @DoruAdryan well, I do not see the problem. You can use min api 9 with the support library. And do not pass null as argument for the inflate method. N.E.V.E.R. Here is why [http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/)

Comment: @CFlex NEVER is a strong statement. For most cases passing a container is indeed the smart thing to do but you can also use `null` if you understand the scenario where you use it and the inflate process. And if the `null` container `inflate()` method was so dangerous the Android engineers wouldn't have put it in the SDK(or at least deprecate it at a later point).

Comment: @Luksprog There are only a few cases where you have to pass null as argument. Inflating a view in a Dialog is one of these. But here, you can have some unexpected behaviors, as all the layout params won't be kept.